# How to access a variable in struts if tag?

Tags: jsp, struts2

Using the code below

```
<%! int role; >

<%
   UserMasterDTO userMasterDTO=(UserMasterDTO)session.getAttribute("userMasterDTO"); 
   role = userMasterDTO.getRole();
%>
```

I want to get this value read by my struts if tag. How to achieve this?
Is below code not the correct way?

```
<s:if test="role == 1">
```

Comment: Please note that using instance variables in a servlet will lead to all sorts of problems in real life; you're exposing a giant security hole since it's a role. That said, this is wrong on multiple levels--there is zero reason to do this using scriptlets. But yes, the code you show is not the correct way: S2 tags get values from the value stack, not servlet instance variables. JSTL tags don't either, btw, although they don't use the value stack.

Answer (score 4):

Try struts 2.x 'if' tag:

```
<s:if test="#session.userMasterDTO.role==1">
```

or

```
<s:set name='role' value=xxxx>
```

Never using java code in jsp/template is a good habit.

Comment: I found the answer
<%! int role; 

 int getRole()
{


System.out.println(role);
 
 return role;

}
%>
 
< s:set var="userrole"><%=getRole()%></s:set>

then i can compare it in if as below

< s:if test="#userrole==1||#userrole==2">

Comment: @user1950540 Just because it's *possible* doesn't mean it's a good idea; this is horrible.

Comment: @imxylz: You need to use `#` to access elements inside session `<s:if test="#session.userMasterDTO.role==1">`